Configuration of vs code for latex (and arara)
I used to use TEXstudio to compile my tex files with arara and this kind of command:
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///arara
% arara: lualatex: {shell: yes, synctex: no, interaction: batchmode}
% arara: lualatex: {shell: yes, synctex: no, interaction: batchmode} if found('log', '(undefined references|Please rerun|Rerun to get)')
% arara: indent : {overwrite: true,silent : yes}

I can't configure the settings json file of vs code with the workshop latex extension on this editor?

Could you please clarify what you are trying to do here? You want to use arara with VSCode? There seems to be a  template repository on GitHub with a recipe but I don't use VSC, so I can't say if it works.

i want to configure the settings.json in vscode for using arara whaen i xompile my .tex files

See the template repository I linked and this section in the latex workshop manual then. Within your VSC config, you have to create a custom latex tool setting for arara which you then refer to in a custom latex recipe setting for the arara workflow.
